# Change configuration of Python linter and fixer with ALE (nvim plugin)

Tags: vim, lint, flake8

I use ALE to manage my linting (with flake8) and code formatting (with black).
One annoying incompatibility between flake8 and black is that flake8 gives an error when a line has more than 80 characters, while black only corrects lines with more than 88 characters.

So I would like to change flake8's line length to 88 characters, or change black's line length to 80 characters.

Notice that I do not have flake8 installed independently from ALE, but I do have black installed independently from ALE.

Comment: you probably want to configure flake8 and/or black via their configuration files

Comment: @AnthonySottile The problem is that I do not find flake8's config file where it would normally be since I did not install it outside ALE, and black does not have such config file as far as I understand from the documentation - it only let's you set a custom line length when ran from the command line.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of flake8, you can configure it with either a `.flake8`, `setup.cfg`, or `tox.ini` file.  for black you configure it using `pyproject.toml`

Comment: @AnthonySottile Thank you, I used pyproject.toml with line-length = 80 and it worked.

Answer (score 15):

You can add the below to your .vimrc file:

```
let g:ale_python_flake8_options = '--max-line-length=88'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify the flake8.vim in:

```
~/.vim/plugged/ale/ale_linters/python/
```

folder and change line:

```
call ale#Set('python_flake8_options', '')
```

into:

```
call ale#Set('python_flake8_options', '--config=$HOME/.config/flake8')
```

Then add all config options in this file.